# Python Server Client WinError 10057

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, network-programming

I'm making a server and client in Python 3.3 using the `socket` module. My server code is working fine, but this client code is returning an error. Here's the code:

```
import socket
import sys
import os

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_address = ('192.168.1.5', 4242)
sock.bind(server_address)

while True:
    command = sock.recv(1024)
    try:
        os.system(command)
        sock.send("yes")
    except:
        sock.send("no")
```

And here's the error:

```
Error in line: command = sock.recv(1024)
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected  and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

What on earth is going on?

Comment: I think you're possibly missing a listener?
try adding sock.listen(5) after you bind.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're confused about when you actually connect to the server, so just remember that you always bind to a local port first. Therefore, this line:

```
server_address = ('192.168.1.5', 4242)
```

Should actually read:

```
server_address = ('', 4242)
```

Then, before your infinite loop, put in the following line of code:

```
sock.connect(('192.168.1.5', 4242))
```

And you should be good to go. Good luck!

EDIT: I suppose I should be more careful with the term "always." In this case, you want to bind to a local socket first.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't accept any requests, and you can only `recv` and/or `send` on the accepted socket in order to communicate with client.

Does your server only need one client to be connected? If so, try this solution:

Try adding the following before the while loop

```
sock.listen(1)         # 1 Pending connections at most
client=sock.accept()   # Accept a connection request
```

In the while loop, you need to change all `sock` to `client` because server socket cannot
be either written or read (all it does is listening at `192.168.1.5:4242`).